# Perl JSON::XS non-OO interface

Tags: json, perl

All of the documentation and examples I have seen for the Perl JSON::XS module use a OO interface, e.g.

```
print JSON::XS->new->ascii()->pretty()->canonical()->encode($in);
```

But I don't necessarily want all those options every time, I'd prefer to send them in a hash like you can with the basic JSON module, e.g.

```
print to_json($in, { canonical => 1, pretty => 1, ascii => 1 } );
```

sending to that encode_json yields

```
Too many arguments for JSON::XS::encode_json
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Re "*But I don't necessarily want all those options every time*", How is it any different with `to_json($in, { canonical => 1, pretty => 1, ascii => 1 } )`???

Comment: Because the to_json call is in a subroutine that takes the hash of options as an argument, so it can easily specify which options the caller wants without having to do a bunch of branching on what is in the hash, e.g.`if (exists($opts->{pretty})) { print JSON::XS->new->pretty()->encode($in) ` as well as every other possible combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON's `to_json` uses JSON::XS if it's installed, so if you want a version of `to_json` that uses `JSON::XS`, simply use the one from JSON.

Or, you could recreate `to_json`.

```
sub to_json
   my $encoder = JSON::XS->new();
   if (@_ > 1) {
      my $opts = $_[1];
      for my $method (keys(%$opts)) {
         $encoder->$_($opts->{$_});
      }
   }

   return $encoder->encode($_[0]);
}
```

But doesn't help stop passing in the options every time. If you're encoding multiple data structures, it's best to create a single object and reuse it.

```
my $encoder = JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->canonical;

print $encoder->encode($in);
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's how it is, but that's ridiculous.

Comment: Ridiculous how? That's exactly what JSON.pm's `to_json` does. And based on another comment you made, it's literally just adding two lines to your sub. (`my $encoder = JSON::XS->new(); $encode->$_($opts->{$_}) for keys %$opts;`)

Comment: It's just less clean than just passing in a hash with the options needed for the particular call; things that look like this are what give my beloved Perl a bad reputation.

Comment: Of course your sub would be cleaner if the module had the same interface as your sub. That's your choice, not Perl's. And Perl made it extremely easy to convert once grin there other!